# How to generate column with row number?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to make an query that will generate column with unique row number generated incrementally. My table with data don't have any unique value.

I was trying to get Gustav script, but I only manage to get it return 1 in every row.

```
Public Function RowCounter( _
  ByVal strKey As String, _
  ByVal booReset As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal strGroupKey As String) _
  As Long

' Builds consecutive RowIDs in select, append or create query
' with the possibility of automatic reset.
' Optionally a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False,CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowCounter(vbNullString, False)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter("",True)=0);
'
' 2002-04-13. Cactus Data ApS. CPH
' 2002-09-09. Str() sometimes fails. Replaced with CStr().
' 2005-10-21. Str(col.Count + 1) reduced to col.Count + 1.
' 2008-02-27. Optional group parameter added.
' 2010-08-04. Corrected that group key missed first row in group.

  Static col      As New Collection
  Static strGroup As String

  On Error GoTo Err_RowCounter

  If booReset = True Then
    Set col = Nothing
  ElseIf strGroup <> strGroupKey Then
    Set col = Nothing
    strGroup = strGroupKey
    col.Add 1, strKey
  Else
    col.Add col.Count + 1, strKey
  End If

  RowCounter = col(strKey)

Exit_RowCounter:
  Exit Function

Err_RowCounter:
  Select Case Err
    Case 457
      ' Key is present.
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      ' Some other error.
      Resume Exit_RowCounter
  End Select

End Function
```

Sql query that I'm trying to get working is like this:

```
SELECT RowCounter("Query1",False) AS RowID, *
FROM Query1
WHERE (RowCounter("Query1",False)<>RowCounter("",True));
```

What am I missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a fixed string as the parameter - and this gets No. 1.

Use the ID of the records of the query, like:

```
SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
```

Comment: Problem is when I try to use that Access ask me to "enter parameter value" as ID.

Comment: `ID` is just a common name of the primary key. Replace it with the actual field name holding the PK of your table/query.

Comment: In my table I don't have primary key, because it don't have any unique values. I import data from txt file to table and have struggled to import it and add unique ID

Comment: Then create a compound key, like: `[TextField] & "|" & CStr([NumberField]) & "|" & [AnotherTextField] & "|" & Format([DateField], "yyyymmdd")`.

Comment: Ugh i feel like I'm going nowhere with those questions. My goal is to get query/table with data sorted by 3 columns and than unique row number based on that - than I want to use query and subquery to sum somethings (thats why I need row number after sorting).
As input to database i have txt file with data log like but not unique. Maybe this will help get to something sane, rather just another way rounds problems...

Comment: I see no going round. The in-line comments show a skeleton for an append query, and I showed you how to concatenate four fields to create something unique to replace a single ID. If several records are not unique, a query cannot be used; loop the records and insert row by row with a counter as the ID.

Comment: I finally managed to get it working! At the end of table where I import my data added autonumber ID field, so it does not interrupts importing. Than I use query to sort that data by 3 fields and save it to temp tbl. And finally I use your script on that temp tbl! I had to use temp tbl because when I used row number on sorted query it showed number before sorting.  
Thanks for your help!